# "Unexpected Token :" using Jest

Tags: react-redux, jestjs, babel-jest

I am currently using jest to testmy react-redux project, but for my first component test the test fails with the error

```
 ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){:root {
                                                                                         ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

  at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript
```

I did some research, can't seem to find any solution.

My .babelrc looks like this

```
"presets": ["react", "es2015", "stage-0"],
"plugins": [
"transform-decorators-legacy",
"transform-class-properties",
"transform-es2015-modules-commonjs"
]
```

Am I missing the right transformer?

Thanks in advance for any help